# How to fetch active threads of another program based on PID in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, unix

We are running two separate JAVA programs in the below mentioned OS and JVM.

**Operating System** : HP-UX 11.11

**JVM Used** : 1.6

**Program 1:**

•   This program monitors a folder for new files using **Apache VFS**.

•   I am using multithreading in this program ,and it creates 5 threads in runtime to process the files in the folder which is being monitored. ( I use **Executor service** for this).

•   This program runs on an **infinite loop**.

•   I am using “**ManagementFactory** class“ to get the PID of this program and I write it to a txt file.

**Program 2:**

• In this program I will get  the PID of the “Program 1” from text file and I want to find all the active threads of “Program1”

• Along with the active threads I would like to know the status whether these 5 threads of “Program1” are currently running/completed state.

Please let me know whether we can **fetch the threads** of another program based on the **PID from JVM**?

Comment: Does jconsole (jmx) tell you anything interesting?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the threads of a program in java by issuing platform specific commands and using JNA (Java Natice Access) to platform specific APIs, for instance under Linux you can issue:

```
ps uH p <PID_OF_U_PROCESS> | wc -l
```

when issuing the ps command you have several details on the process, for instance whether it's a zombie process or how much memory and processor it is using..

Under Windows you'll use similar command

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using JMX. Something like

```
for (final VirtualMachineDescriptor vmd : VirtualMachine.list()) {
    int pid;
    try {
        if ((pid = Integer.parseInt(vmd.id())) == myPidOfInterest) {
            String address = ConnectorAddressLink.importFrom(pid)));    
            MBeanServerConnection connection = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(address).getMBeanServerConnection();

            ThreadMXBean threadMxBean = ManagementFactory.newPlatformMXBeanProxy(connection, "java.lang:type=Threading", ThreadMXBean.class);

            // Now you have the ThreadMXBean you can find out all kinds of things about the threads
            for (long threadId : threadMxBean.getAllThreadIds()) {
                System.out.println(threadMxBean.getThreadInfo(threadId));
            }
        }

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // ignore  
    }

}
```